# Primefaces datatable - rowIndexvar not shown properly when using p:dataExporter for a p:dataTable

Tags: datatable, primefaces

I was following the example for `p:dataExporter` as in the [primefaces showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/exporterHome.jsf). When using with `rowIndexVar` for indexing, the exported data is not indexed properly although it is indexed accurately in the datatable, i.e., the display in web page is accurate. But, in case of data exporter, all row serials are shown as "1" in the generated documents. Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a bug, please create an issue ticket in PrimeFaces tracker